# troubles with moderncv after Miktex update

Tags: moderncv

I have been using moderncv to generate some cover letters and CVs recently. Everything was working fine, until I have done a Miktex update. I keep getting the error `Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle` for the following MWE (Which used to worjk without any problems!):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage[scale=0.82]{geometry} \geometry{textheight=25cm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  %\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedright% \raggedleft
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\makebox[2\textwidth]{\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname\hfill\normalfont\textcolor{black}{\@date}}}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[3em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage} \\[2em]
  % date
  %\hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  %\@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}} 

\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{29}\mdseries\upshape}

\makeatother

%\patchcmd{\makeletterclosing}{[2em]}{[1em]}{}{}
\firstname{XXXXXX} % Your first name
\familyname{XXXXXX} 
\title{CV}
\address{XXXXXX,12}{12345,XXXXXX}
\email{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXX.XXX}
\begin{document}
\recipient{XXXX}{XXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXX\\1234 XXXXXX\\XXXXXX} 
\date{\today} % Letter date
\opening{blablabla,} % Opening greeting
\closing{blablabla} % Closing phrase
\enclosure[Im Anhang]{CV} % List of enclosed documents

\makelettertitle % Print letter title
\blindtext[3]
\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature
\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Lebenslauf
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage

\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

\section{EDV- Kenntnisse}

\cvitem{Tool}{C, C++, VHDL}
\cvitem{Betriebssystem}{Unix, Windows}
\cvitem{Simulations-Tools}{Tool, Tool, Tool II, Tool}

%---------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** 
Following the log file, the errors are the following:

- `Undefined control sequence. \setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}`
- `Missing number, treated as zero. \renewcommand`
- `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \renewcommand`

Which are respectively originating from the two commands:

```
 \setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{24}{29}\mdseries\upshape}
```

Comment: Try to change `\renewcommand` to `\newcommand`.

Comment: Check if you have a local copy of [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) or some of its components in your working folder.

Comment: @Werner. I just removed all local copies, but Still the problem is persisting

Comment: @Sigur, I just found out the problem is coming from the line '\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{12cm}' but i still can't solve it

Comment: @user2536125: You don't even have that in your code...

Comment: @Werner , weired. I had to edit my code once to add it, but it seems it wasn't taken into consideration. I will add it again.

Comment: The length is not defined. `\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}`

Comment: @Johannes_B your comment (combined with the answer from @Werner) contributed to the answer. Please add it seperately, so I can accept it as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\makecvtitlenamewidth` existed as part of [`moderncv` 1.5.0](https://launchpad.net/moderncv/trunk/1.5.0/+download/moderncv-1.5.0.zip), but was removed from [`moderncv` 1.5.1](https://launchpad.net/moderncv/trunk/1.5.1/+download/moderncv-1.5.1.zip) - the current latest version.

The current replacement seems to be `\makecvheadnamewidth`, which a default of `0pt` (used in conditioning for an automatically set width).

The class has undergone numerous changes which makes older versions of documents incompatible with current versions. If you wish to keep the older formats, you need to [maintain a temporary version of the class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764). Otherwise, you'll have to update your documents accordingly.