# Moderncv - undefined control sequence in minimal document

Tags: moderncv, undefined

Attempting to compile the following minimal working example fails on my TeX installation.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
%\moderncvstyle{banking}

\begin{document}
    Foo
\end{document}
```

The log file repeats the following error eight times:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
            {}~\@lastname {}
l.6 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

The error remains the same whether I'm using pdflatex or luatex to compile. I'm using a fresh (full) TeX Live 2016 installation and tlmgr revision 41476 in Linux Mint and I'm using TeXstudio as my editor. According to `tlmgr update --all` and `tlmgr update --self` my installation is up to date.

Uncommenting the style statement results in an additional warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `moderncvheadiii',
               but the package provides `moderncvheadiii'.
```

I found a few mentions of this online, but it seems this issue was fixed by a moderncv update (https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/1).

Peculiarly, I can update and re-compile an older moderncv document (that was made on another distribution) without any issues. Other document classes also seem to work correctly.

How would I go about troubleshooting an issue like this?

**EDIT**

Thank you @Elad Den for pointing out that I need to define names in the document's preamble. Both `\name{}{}` and `\firstname{}` `\familyname{}` work, although my editor does not recognise the former command. This does indeed allow me to compile without any issues.

Unfortunately it wasn't smooth sailing from here on out. Adding `\recipients{}`, `\opening{}`, `\closing{}` and `\makeletterclosing` work fine, but adding `\makelettertitle` results in the following errors:

```
Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle
You have requested package `moderncvheadiii', but the package provides `moderncvheadiii'.
You have requested package `moderncvbodyiii', but the package provides `moderncvbodyiii'.
```

Remarkably, I *do* receive a (seemingly) correct pdf output, despite the mess of errors and warnings in my log file.

I've found one reference to a similar issue, but no solutions were offered in this thread: [Problem with moderncv or TexStudio: makelettertitle is undefined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304421/problem-with-moderncv-or-texstudio-makelettertitle-is-undefined)

Comment: regarding your update, check this out https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263915/troubles-with-moderncv-after-miktex-update  if this does not help, I suggest starting a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like (since this is a CV) the documentclass is expecting `\firstname{}` and `\familyname{}` to be defined. You could add those lines to the preamble or use the `\name{}{}` command

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
%\moderncvstyle{banking}

%\firstname{}
%\familyname{}

\name{}{}

\begin{document}
    Foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have solved the issue for this minimal document! However, I'm afraid I immediately run into more issues when I use the \makelettertitle command: "Undefined control sequence. \makelettertitle". At least one person has run into this issue before, but it's unclear whether he managed to solve it or not: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304421/problem-with-moderncv-or-texstudio-makelettertitle-is-undefined

Comment: It seems his problem was solved by updating texlive. If I were you I'd try that, and if the problem persists, come back to TeX.SX and ask another question :)